# Explanation of this equation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $P: H \rightarrow H$ a linear mapping satisfying $P^2 = P$. Show that

$$F := ranP, P = P_F$$

with

$$ranP := \{Px | x \in H\}$$

Could someone please explain to me what $$P = P_F$$ means? What is $P_F$?

Any hints are more than welcome.

Comment: $P_F$ must be certainly the restriction of $P$ to $F$. And $P$ is a proyector.

Comment: So this means I have to show that $P$ is equal to its range?

Comment: $P$ is an operator and $F$ a subspace of $H$. No means of making equal two entities of distinct nature. Read books or references about Hilbert spaces and linear operators.